# nix-shell: how to load environment variables from env file?

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

Related to this question: [nix-shell: how to specify a custom environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27713707/799785)

With this derivation:

```hs
stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  FOO = "bar";
}
```

`FOO` will be available in the nix shell as an environment variable, but is it possible to load environment variables from an env file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`nix-shell`](https://nixos.org/nix/manual)'s `shellHook` to load environment variables from a file by [sourcing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-source) them as shell code. For example:

```
stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "my-shell";
  shellHook = ''
    # Mark variables which are modified or created for export.
    set -a
    source env.sh
    # or to make it relative to the directory of this shell.nix file
    # source ${toString ./env.sh}
    set +a
  '';
}
```

You could switch from `stdenv.mkDerivation` to [`mkShell`](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/index.html#sec-pkgs-mkShell) if your shell isn't also a package.

Comment: Almost, in my case should be `set -a; source .env; set+a`, since in a .env file you don't explicitly export the variables. Other problem is that it doesn't work in combination with direnv

Comment: Thanks! I've added it to my answer. But what's the problem with direnv? You could change `env.sh` to `.envrc` if you want to load its file. Was direnv part of the question?

Comment: `direnv` was not part of the question, I should create another question for that, but I was confused because the variables were not loaded by `direnv`. Not sure what is the problem, but while with `nix-shell` it works, with `direnv` + `lorri` I get this error (running `lorri shell`): `/nix/store/...-stdenv-linux/setup: line 83: /home/myuser/direnv-test/env.sh: No such file or directory`. I solved it replacing `source ${toString ./env.sh}` with `source ${./env.sh}`

Comment: `lorri` runs the `shellHook` inside the Nix sandbox, so that makes sense. `${./env.sh}` puts the env file in the Nix store so it is available. `${toString ./env.sh}` used the file in place so that `$0` and `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` worked as usual in `nix-shell`. That doesn't seem feasible with `lorri`.